# How to center two subtable that are on the same line

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a problem because I cannot centere two table that are on the same line. I tried many times, with different methods but it doesn't work.
The code that I use is the following.:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{subtable}[c]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\raggedright
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Event Window +/-1 days}} \\
\midrule
Min.    & -0.0238395 \\
1st Qu. & -0.0020889 \\
Median  & +0.0005291 \\
Mean    & +0.0006262 \\
3rd Qu. & +0.0048530 \\
Max.    & +0.0190593 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}[c]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\raggedright
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Event Window +/-5 days}} \\
\midrule
Min.    & -0.019635 \\
1st Qu. & -0.002735 \\
Median  & +0.001202  \\
Mean    & +0.000585 \\
3rd Qu. & +0.003947 \\
Max.    & +0.013458 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Descriptive and Explorative analysis for SIX Exchange Swiss Performance Index. Source: \cite{rproject2008xx} output}
\label{table:SPI MSCI beta}
\end{table}
```

The result that I obtain every time is the following:
[image]

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Remove `\raggedright`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\raggedright` killed `\centering`. So removing them will work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{subtable}[c]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Event Window +/-1 days}} \\
\midrule
Min.    & -0.0238395 \\
1st Qu. & -0.0020889 \\
Median  & +0.0005291 \\
Mean    & +0.0006262 \\
3rd Qu. & +0.0048530 \\
Max.    & +0.0190593 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}[c]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Event Window +/-5 days}} \\
\midrule
Min.    & -0.019635 \\
1st Qu. & -0.002735 \\
Median  & +0.001202  \\
Mean    & +0.000585 \\
3rd Qu. & +0.003947 \\
Max.    & +0.013458 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Descriptive and Explorative analysis for SIX Exchange Swiss Performance Index. Source: [something] output}
\label{table:SPI MSCI beta}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]